# How to pass the jwt token from ReactNative to webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I have a login screen in the react-native mobile app. When a user enters the correct Email and password, then I store the jwt token in the react-native app, but not in the webview.
After the login screen, I want to show a webview(Dashboard).
How to skip the login screen because the user is already authenticated in react-native-app?
How to pass the jwt token to webview so that the user does not need authentication again.
[Click to see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjcT5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the token with the `URL` in the `WebView` component with query param:

```
const myToken="1234";

// rest of the codes ...

source={{uri: `https://prelive-crm.new.pabau.com/clients?app=1&token=${myToken}`}}
```

**Note:** the maximum possible length of the query string is **2048** characters. read more on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string#:%7E:text=Although%20officially%20there%20is%20no,a%20max%20of%202048%20characters.).

**Note:** You need to get the **token** param within your website.